# XPages: do not allow identical values in radio groups

Tags: javascript, xpages, lotus-domino

I have a group of 6 radio groups on an xPage, each with a list of values 1-6. I am looking for a method to allow the user to only select each number once. A user will not be able to pick the number 1 for radioGroup1 and radioGroup2.

I am struggling to come up with a good way to do this.

The two methods I thought of were building an array in js, using the array for the values in the radioGroup, then removing values picked from the array and doing a partial refresh on the other radioGroups.

The second method was simply wipe the value of a radioGroup if the duplicate value was detected in another radioGroup.

I guess I could just do a validator to compare the values on the submit.

Any thoughts on the best way to approach this in xPages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a twofold approach:

1. Client side: add an onChange listener to the radio buttons. When a value changes you run through the buttons and disable (gray out) the same number in the other radio groups. This is fast and good for the user since the UI doesn't "dance". You need a "picking" order. e.g. a column left (if organized in columns) can always overwrite the right column(s). You also need to eventually clear a radio button before disabling it
2. On the server side have a validator (one function called by all) that double checks that - in case someone tries to trick you with Firebug

Bonus Idea:
Radio buttons are bad for this type of UI (they are good as backing data store). Overlay them with a background graphic based on the radio button state like a checkmark, an empty square (for selectable) or a gray X (for disabled). Would make a great custom control.